# List<int> from method parameters return 0 as default first value in C# MVC ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have checked the parameters in chrome network inspection tool. and it's null.
but when I get the data from the actionResult it has a member and it's zero.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyInputDto input)
{
    var data = input.ItemList;
    //the data variable is a list with one member and that's zero;
    return view();
}
```

and this is my MyInputDto:

```cs
public class MyInputDto
{
    public MyInputDto()
    {
        this.ItemList = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<int> ItemList { get; set; }
}
```

and the request is something like this:

```js
var itemList = ($('#input_selector').val() != null ? $('#input_selector').val() : []).map(x => parseInt(x));

$.post('@Url.Action("Index")'
                    , {
                        ItemList: itemList
                    })
                .done((data) => {
                    $('[data-table-container]').html(data);
                })
```

the reason I use parseInt(x) is that if I don't the data will be sent like this `"1,2,3,4"` and the ActionResult method doesn't recognize it as a list of integers

how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the code for the view?

Comment: it's an ajax call. I will update the question

Comment: So u are saying that `data.Count` equals 1 and `data[0]` gives u `0`?

Comment: @akg179 yes, I do.

Comment: I think you forgot to pass the **data** to your view in **Index** action.